# Implement Night Mode (like Google Sky Map)

Tags: android

I'm writing an application which will be used at night and would really benefit from a Red 'Night Mode' like Google Sky Map has.

Can anyone provide any advice on how I'd go about this please. Would it be a theme or some sort of overlay?

Regards,
Mike

Answer (score 1):

I'm a developer on Sky Map.  We actually don't use a theme - I'd like to take that approach as then we could easily redden all of the UI controls, but I couldn't work out a way of changing a theme dynamically.  Let me know if you succeed!  Instead, we redden all of the graphics in on the map using our own code (this is all done in OpenGL)

Answer (score -1):

I know its not really answering your question but just as a pointer you might want to look at [Cyanogenmod](http://www.cyanogenmod.com/). I have it installed on my phone and it has a night mode like this. Entire screen goes into a "red" mode.